# How to code more than 1 button in mainactivity without errors?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a little project using Kotlin in Android Studio and I keep getting an error which I cannot make sense of. When I add 'sdkButton_2' part in the code, OpenDialogue box becomes an unresolved reference. I know this is not correct because it works fine when I just have that one button. I have tried adding a separate function for each button but that obviously doesn't work, and I'm not too sure what else to do from here. Any ideas would be appreciated. I've copied and pasted the code below. (OpenDialogueBox is a funtion I've added further down in the code. I don't think its relevant to the current issue but let me know if you need to see it).

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var sdkButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sdk_button)
    sdkButton.setOnClickListener{
        openDialogueBox()

val sdkButton_2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sdk_button_2)
    sdkButton_2.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, secondaryactivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Can you put the error you are getting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, one bracket is missing or you have some different name in the XML file. check once

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

var sdkButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sdk_button)
sdkButton.setOnClickListener{
    openDialogueBox()
}

val sdkButton_2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sdk_button_2)
sdkButton_2.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(this, secondaryactivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I picked this one as best because I feel that it will give a good example to future readers who make the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the fact that you are not closing the braces  of the `buttonName.setOnClickListener` at both buttons.

Comment: woww. yep this did it. What an easy mistake that I spent hours trying to fix. Thanks!

P.S. I picked the other answer as best because the example might help beginner coders in the future. Hope you don't mind. I can't upvote either as it turns out new people on stackoverflow can't, I need reps first :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did not define the `R.id.sdk_button_2` in the xml file.
Share your xml too so we can say for certain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turns out it was just the above answer and I forgot the brace.